# Should i be using a WHILE loop in this stored procedure or is there another way to get the same result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I'm making a stored procedure to check a number of days against a user inputted date for a holiday booking application, obviously if the number of users off is greater than the number of users allowed off at one time then it will throw an error, this loop works ( i think ) but i've read elsewhere that you should try to avoid loops in SQL anyway so i was looking for a little bit of help! heres my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBusinessRuleValidation
(
@StartDate DATE,
@EndDate DATE,
@EmployeeID INT
)


/****
Name: spdolater
description: checks business rules
****/

AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @JobRoleID INT
        DECLARE @MaxJobTypeAllowedOff INT       
        DECLARE @MaxEmployeesAllowedOff INT
        DECLARE @DateCount INT
        DECLARE @SameJobRoleOff INT
        DECLARE @DateCheck DATE

        SET @JobRoleID = (SELECT JobRoleID FROM Employees WHERE @EmployeeID = Employees.ID)
        SET @MaxJobTypeAllowedOff = (SELECT MaxEmployeesAllowedOff FROM JobRole WHERE @JobRoleID = JobRole.ID)
        SET @MaxEmployeesAllowedOff = 20
        SET @DateCheck = @StartDate
        SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @EndDate)

        WHILE (@DateCheck <> @EndDate)
        BEGIN
            SET @DateCount = (SELECT COUNT (@DateCheck) FROM Holidays)
            IF @DateCount > @MaxEmployeesAllowedOff
            BEGIN
                /*error*/
            END


            SET @SameJobRoleOff = (SELECT COUNT (*) JobRoleID
            FROM Employees
            RIGHT JOIN Holidays
            ON Employees.ID = Holidays.EmployeeID
            WHERE @EmployeeID = Employees.ID
            AND @DateCheck = Holidays.StartDate)

            IF @SameJobRoleOff > @MaxJobTypeAllowedOff
            BEGIN
                /*error*/
            END

            SET @DateCheck = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateCheck)
        END


    END
```

if you would like me to explain the code and logic a little more please ask.

inb4 OP loves variables :)

Comment: We all love variables. Ergo we love OP.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `(SELECT COUNT (@StartDate) FROM Holidays)`

Comment: It counts the number of Holidays that have the same start date from the Holidays table and if its over 20 then it will automatically not be allowed to book off, it should be DateCheck really but i just forgot my bad :P -edited so its now DateCheck rather than StartDate @ypercube

Comment: No, it will count all the rows in the `Holidays` table, as long as what you have inside the `COUNT()` is not null (and no matter what you have there). You probably want `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Holidays WHERE somecolumn = @DateCheck)`

Comment: I think thats what i was getting at, its been a long day haha, thanks :) @ypercube

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you should never use loops in SQL.  SQL works using sets and you have to think of your problem in terms of sets.

It is clear the code you have listed above as written will not work and has not been tested.  It could be written this way but will be slow.

Lets think in terms of sets to solve the problem and work iteratively to solve the problem.  In this way if I don't understand your model or your business rules it will be easy for you to correct.

In general, you want to check all the dates between start and end date to see if there are any which fail your criteria check.

So to start, find all these dates (as a set) like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Holidays AS H
WHERE H.Date BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate
```

To find the count for each day

```
SELECT count(*) as [takenbydate], H.Date
FROM Holidays AS H
WHERE H.Date BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate
GROUP BY H.Date
```

or

```
SELECT Count() OVER (PARTITION BY H.Date) AS C, *
FROM Holidays AS H
WHERE H.Date BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate
```

Now we want to check the max allowed.  To do this we join to the max allowed table we also join to the employee table to get the job role information, as far as I know there is no dates in the max allowed table.  If there is then you need another `AND` clause in the join statement.

```
SELECT Count() OVER (PARTITION BY H.Date) AS C, R.MaxEmployeesAllowedOff, H.*
FROM Holidays AS H
JOIN Employees AS E ON E.ID = @EmployeeID 
JOIN JobRole AS R ON R.ID = E.JobRoleID
WHERE H.Date BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate
```

Now we check the rules

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT Count() OVER (PARTITION BY H.Date) AS C, R.MaxEmployeesAllowedOff, H.*
  FROM Holidays AS H
  JOIN Employees AS E ON E.ID = @EmployeeID 
  JOIN JobRole AS R ON R.ID = E.JobRoleID
  WHERE H.Date BETWEEN @startdate and @enddate
) sub
WHERE MaxEmployeesAllowedOff < C OR C > 20
```

If this query returns any results you have a problem.

> Note, I added all fields from Holiday for information, but the final
>   query would not need these columns.  Any results from the final query
>   would show an error should be thrown and all that is needed is the
>   first two columns for the rules as you presented them.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL so ill be asking a lot of questions, starting with the H.Date, im finding it hard to understand which column this is going to be in my holiday table, my column names are ID, EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDAte, Duration, Status and Reason, and i dont know which it should be haha @hogan

Comment: @Jimmy_Chong -- this is a hard problem -- you actually have multiple overlapping ranges and you want to count intersections by day.  I don't have time to write a solution right now -- but maybe knowing what your problem space is can help you edit the question to make it clearer.